# Xcode 7 insert a new line and go to

Tags: xcode7

Is there a keyboard shortcut to go to a newline regardless of where is the cursor currently at?
notice the cursor before the last closing " and want to go to a newline in a keyboard shortcut.

```
var myName = "Jeff|" 
var age = "55"
```

expected

```
var myName = "Jeff"
|  <--- new line 
var age = "55"
```

thx

Comment: You could use the arrow down key. Or I completely don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Like in JetBeans ^+Shift+Enter moves the cursor to a new line from wherever it is even in the middle of the line.

Comment: Again, way don't you use the arrow down key?

Comment: that will move the cursor to the line of code below the current line but I want to insert a newline. i.e. command + right arrow "go to end of line" + Enter to make a new line and place the cursor at the beginning.

Comment: I see. I think Xcode doesn't have such a short cut.

Comment: Six years later.... Is it possible?